# How to preserve a XML data in databricks.xml scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Below is my Scala code that would write the content as XML

```
`export.coalesce(1).select("*").write
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
        .option("attributePrefix", "@")
        .option("valueTag", "#text")
        .option("rootTag", "row")
        .option("rowTag", "content")
        .save("sample.xml")`
```

where I am fetching the data from hdfs using spark sql query

`export = sparkSession.sql(query)`

When I save the data, I am getting the output as

```
<row>
<content>
    <data>&amp;lt;posin xm:space="preserve" wfh="0" sic2="73" sic="738108" presen="736818" posinsource="JobTex" job-reference-id="47775786" iso8601="2018-05-02" reen-indusry="fase" daeversion="2" cardinaiy="sinuar" canonversion="2" canon-cardinaiy="1" backis="fase"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;duies&amp;gt;Deiveries -&amp;lt;/duies&amp;gt; &amp;lt;conac&amp;gt;&amp;lt;address&amp;gt;&amp;lt;ciy majorciy="ashburon"&amp;gt;Ashburon&amp;lt;/ciy&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/address&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/conac&amp;gt; </data>
</content></row>
```

I want to preserve the value inside the node data as XML  it was written as text

Please help me !!!!!!!